# Apache MOD REWRITE basic question?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a very basic question. I am using RewriteRule to make my links bit pretty. Here is a part of the rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule first-link.php index.php?page=1
RewriteRule second-link.php index.php?page=3
RewriteRule third-link.php index.php?page=2
RewriteRule fourth-link.php index.php?page=4
```

The problem is that whenever I visit fourth-link.php, third-link.php, second-link.php, it display content first-link.php!!!!
Any suggestions to make it work without changing pretty link names.

Thanks